# Image comes out of the row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an image inside `row > col-md-6`.

I wish to move the image to the right of its column.

I created the below two classes - `.pos1` and `.pos2`

```
.pos1 {
    position: relative;
}
.pos2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

On using these classes, the image comes out of the row and its no more responsive.

The html code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <title>My Faourite App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <h1 class="title">MY FAVORITE APP</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 pos1">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="img-responsive pos2" alt="hello">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div>In ac ipsum quis turpis adipiscing commodo. Mauris fermentum quam.<div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong.
I am trying this on both, IE12 and Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `position: absolute` it's (almost) always a problem. Try to use bootstrap class `pull-right` and `clearfix` instead of your `.pos1` and `.pos2`. The pull-right class goes on the image and the clearfix class on the parent of the image. Check if that works.

Answer (score 1):

you may use this classes:

```
.row {position:relative;overflow:hidden;}
.pos1 {position:absolute; right:0; height:100%;}
.pos1 img {position:absolute; right:0; height:100%;}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3gdegt52/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove both:

```
.pos1 {
    position: relative;
}
.pos2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Neither are needed as `.col-md-6` is already `position:relative` and you can use bootstrap helper classes like `.pull-right`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick with the pull-right method though. When you get smaller than `col-ms-6` it acts like a floating graphic. Making text wrap around it. The simplest thing to do is just add `img{margin-left:auto;}` and forget about the excess css.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6g7h4yLd/3/)

Also, if you want all of your other elements to line up with the `container` you need to put some type of `col-{size}-{number}` otherwise your margins won't line up.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!--Adding 'col-md-12' allows the margins to line up with other 'col-' items-->
        <div class="col-md-12">
             <h1 class="title">MY FAVORITE APP</h1>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="img-responsive" alt="hello" style='margin-left:auto;' />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div>In ac ipsum quis turpis adipiscing commodo. Mauris fermentum quam.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```